# Не пойму, почему Ajax JQuery работает так

Tags: javascript, ajax

Я не могу понять, почему он выполняет сначала 1, потом 3, потом 2?

Снизу код, а еще ниже - вывод консоли.

Тут есть какая-то джаваскриптерская хитрость или я что-то не понимаю?

```js
function serverRequest(url, params) {
    var ajaxContent = null;

    if (params === undefined) {
        console.log('without parameters'); // 1
        $.ajax({ // 2
            url: '../backend/' + url + '.php',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('response : ' + data);
                ajaxContent = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log('response parse : ' + ajaxContent);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                ajaxContent = "error";
                console.log('ERROR');
            },
        });
        console.log('ajaxContent = ' + ajaxContent); // 3
    }
}
```

- without parameters
- ajaxContent = null
- response : "OK"
- response parse : OK

Comment: Не удивительно. Запрос-то асинхронный и его никто не обязан ждать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX — Asynchronous Javascript And Xml (**асинхронный** JavaScript и XML).  Это значит, что пока идёт передача данных, пользователь может совершать другие, необходимые ему действия.

Перецитировав одного из [великих](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178779/pavel-mayorov)

> Проблема в том, что в коде нет операции ожидания. Ни подписка на событие, ни AJAX-вызов, ни даже вызов API не ждут поступления данных - а сразу же передают управление дальше.

Поэтому строка `console.log('ajaxContent = ' + ajaxContent);` выполняется *ДО* того, как переменная ajax получит ответ.